Can I travel with my child to the UK if I am not the person named in their visitor's visa?
In April my child travelled with her school to the UK and the teacher's name is in her visa as the accompanying adult.
Her visa is still valid and we would like to take a family trip there during the summer holidays. Obviously the teacher will not be joining us.
As her mum, can I take her to the UK on the same visa? Or do we need a new one with no named adult in it?
Thanks in advance for your help.

I think you probably need to get a new visa.
Guidance on Accompanied children (visa nationals) states that the passport number(s) of the adult(s) accompanying a child must be entered on the vignette. The vignette will have an endorsement stating Only valid if acc. by [passport # of adult].
I recommend that you check with UKVI.
